# iOS 11.0 Core Data NSException when inverse relationship is set

Tags: core-data, swift3, ios11

This issue happened today for the first time and I haven't been able to find anything on the subject.

**Problem**: When setting the value of a to-one relationship in Core Data the app crashes with a NSException in iOS >11 only. The only way to stop this from happening is to remove the inverse relationship. This fixes the NSException but presents other problems later on.

**Setup**: We have a `Feed` and `User` managed object. `Feed.author` is a a to-one relationship to the User NSManagedObject, and `User.authored` is a to-many relationship to Feed NSManagedObjects.

This setup is working perfect in version of iOS < 11.0, but in 11 >= it crashes with a NSException when I set the `author` for a feed or I add to `User.addToFeeds(..)`.

Is there anything I may be missing from the setup or has anyone encountered something similar?

**User setup**
[image]

**Feed setup**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i've solved the problem.

The solution was surprising and not at all what I the NSExceptions pointed to. In my NSManagedObject class of Feed (I had extended it) I created a computed variable isAuthor to determine if the currently logged in user is the author of this feed. Well that caused a bunch of weird errors that were hard to track. I changed the name of that variable, but you can find a writeup on it at http://mikeabdullah.net/nsmanagedobject-method-kvc-clash.html